# Wagtail - adding blogs to the homepage when not using home_page.html

Tags: django, customization, posts, wagtail

Instead of using Wagtail for all pages, I added Wagtail to an existing site based on Edge v2. I have customized the install of wagtail by creating a news app (instead of blog app) and changing the names of pages to NewsIndexPage, etc. This means I don't have a models.py in the main app folder. For some reason it also means the news page is at pages/news instead of /news.

I want to display posts on this home page but having changed the name(s) to news from blog, and not using the HomePage model I'm confused on how to make that happen. I'm thinking I should be able to add to the "context" in the views.py to make this happen but whatever I tried didn't seem to work.

Being new I'm sure I've missed something, but I'm having a ton of fun learning this stuff, and would appreciate any guidance in making this work.

Here's the news/models.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models

# New imports added for ClusterTaggableManager, TaggedItemBase, MultiFieldPanel

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey, ParentalManyToManyField
from modelcluster.contrib.taggit import ClusterTaggableManager
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase

from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page, Orderable
from wagtail.wagtailcore.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, InlinePanel, MultiFieldPanel
from wagtail.wagtailimages.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from wagtail.wagtailsearch import index
from wagtail.wagtailsnippets.models import register_snippet

from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

@register_snippet
class NewsCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    icon = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+'
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        ImageChooserPanel('icon'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'news categories'


class NewsIndexPage(Page):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super(NewsIndexPage, self).get_context(request)

        # Get the full unpaginated listing of resource pages as a queryset -
        # replace this with your own query as appropriate
        blogpages = self.get_children().live().order_by('-first_published_at')

        paginator = Paginator(blogpages, 6) # Show 6 resources per page

        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            blogpages = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            blogpages = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
            blogpages = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        # make the variable 'resources' available on the template
        context['blogpages'] = blogpages

        return context


class NewsPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey('NewsPage', related_name='tagged_items')

class NewsTagIndexPage(Page):

    def get_context(self, request):

        # Filter by tag
        tag = request.GET.get('tag')
        blogpages = NewsPage.objects.filter(tags__name=tag)

        # Update template context
        context = super(NewsTagIndexPage, self).get_context(request)
        context['blogpages'] = blogpages
        return context

class NewsPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=NewsPageTag, blank=True)
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField('news.NewsCategory', blank=True)

    def main_image(self):
        gallery_item = self.gallery_images.first()
        if gallery_item:
            return gallery_item.image
        else:
            return None

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('intro'),
        index.SearchField('body'),
    ]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('date'),
            FieldPanel('tags'),
            FieldPanel('categories', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
        ], heading="News information"),
        FieldPanel('intro'),
        FieldPanel('body'),
        InlinePanel('gallery_images', label="Gallery images"),
    ]

class NewsPageGalleryImage(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(NewsPage, related_name='gallery_images')
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+'
    )
    caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)

    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('caption'),
    ]
```

In the mysite/views.py I have the HomePage defined:

```
from django.views import generic
from contact.forms import ContactForm

class HomePage(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context=super(HomePage, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['form'] = ContactForm

        return context
```

Comment: Regarding the URL of the `NewsIndexPage` have a look at `urls.py`. I suspect you have `url(r'pages', include(wagtail_urls))` instead of `url(r'', include(wagtail_urls))` for the Wagtail pages to be served from the root (note: make sure to add it after all your vanilla Django routes, otherwise it will intercept everything).

Comment: As for showing the news articles on the homepage, try `context['news'] = NewsPage.objects.live().order_by('-first_published_at').specific()`

Comment: thanks, the url worked but the NewsPage objects did not.  First issue was the code errored on ".specific().  When I removed that it didn't error out. 
 I'm using the code below in the homepage

        {% for news in page.news %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <a class="blog-post-link" href="{% pageurl blog %}">
            <h3>{{ news.title }}</h3>
        </a>
        <div class="blog-intro">
            {{ news.body }}
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% pageurl blog %}">Read More &raquo;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
        {% endfor %}

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should use `news` not `page.news`.

Comment: That worked - want to propose that as the answer so that I can mark it as such?

Comment: Done thank you. I've removed `specific` from the answer since it was causing a crash for you, and because after looking at it, it isn't necessary here. Indeed, we're already querying `NewsPage`s so it's already the right object. `specific` is only needed when querying with a parent class, for example Wagtail Page's model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting the discussion from the comment since it resolved the issue.

Regarding the URL of the `NewsIndexPage` have a look at urls.py. I suspect you have `url(r'pages', include(wagtail_urls))` instead of `url(r'', include(wagtail_urls))` for the Wagtail pages to be served from the root. However make sure to add it after all your vanilla Django routes, otherwise it will intercept everything.

As for showing the news articles on the homepage, try adding `context['news'] = NewsPage.objects.live().order_by('-first_published_at')` to `get_context_data`. This will be available in the template as `news`.